# How do you generate a random number in a range with a specific average in python?

Tags: python, math, random

So lets say I want to generate a random number between -1000 and 1000 and I want the average to be x. How would I do this?

Edit: just to be clear, the numbers generated should fall in a standard normal distribution with an average of x.

So if I generated a thousand numbers and found the average of them it would be x.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sum_ = 0
for i in range(0, 10):
  sum_ += random.triangular(-1000, 1000, 10)
print sum_ / 10
```

and I want this to give me something ~10 but I'm obviously not using the right code.

Comment: random int or random float?

Comment: You have tried anything?

Comment: I am new to coding, I tried random.triangular, but it doesn't seem to be what I want. And float or int doesn't matter at this point.

Comment: You must include in your post the code you have tried, and indicate where is your problem. Since you are a new user, read the StackOverflow FAQ.

Comment: here is some useful documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: You seem to be using terms without knowing what they mean. A normal distribution always has infinite range, and the *standard* normal distribution is the normal distribution whose mean is zero and standard deviation is one. So it's impossible to construct "a" standard normal distribution with your criteria.

Comment: The normal distribution has two parameters, the mean which determines the location, and either the variance or the standard deviation to define the shape.  Additional information is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: See my answer below for some additional thoughts. The answer you accepted does not do what your question asks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    normalvariate(self, mu, sigma) method of Random instance
    Normal distribution.

    mu is the mean, and sigma is the standard deviation.
```

i.e.

```
import random
x= random.normalvariate(2,17)
```

Here 2 is the mean, and 17 is the standard deviation. If you want to scale linearly you would add and multiply by the appropriate values.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer???

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades because this is the answer. It solves both the average and distribution issue in two lines of code

Comment: No it don't! How can he provide the value for standard deviation when OP wants the number between -1000 and 1000?

Comment: This doesn't handle the `-1000 1000` requirement.

Comment: Technically, it's impossible to satisfy the limits requirement and the normal distribution requirement.

Comment: @DavidZ Couldn't you just "cut off" values which are over a limit and then for each value over a limit calculate a new one, until you have a desired number of values? Name it "cut off normal distribution" if you want.

Comment: @Zelphir Indeed, that's exactly one of the suggestions I made in my answer. My point here is just that the truncated normal distribution, as it's called, is technically not a normal distribution. (Of course the difference is not relevant in many cases, but we don't know if the situation faced by the asker was one of those.)

Answer (score 6):

The standard normal distribution has infinite range, there is a non-null probability of finding points outside any given interval. You could use [triangular](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.triangular), just remember that the mean is `(a + b + mode) / 3` so `triangular(a, b, 3*x - a - b)` will get you what you want:

```
from random import triangular

a = 0
b = 10
x = 3
test = [triangular(a, b, 3*x - a - b) for _ in range(1000)]
sum(test) / 1000.0
# 3.006828109140065
```

Comment: Remember this doesn't satisfies normal distribution requirement.

Comment: @Christian, the OP added the normal distribution requirement in an edit. Because this requirement is incompatible with his first limit requirement I just left my answer unmodified and added a note.

Answer (score 4):

As several comments have mentioned, these two requirements conflict with each other:

> I want to generate a random number between -1000 and 1000

and

> the numbers generated should fall in a standard normal distribution with an average of x

because a standard [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) has an infinite domain. If you choose numbers from a normal distribution, there will be some probability that you get a value greater than 1000 or less than -1000. Conversely, if you do anything to limit the range to [-1000,1000], then you will not be drawing from a normal distribution.

One option is to generate numbers according to a truncated normal distribution, which is just like a standard normal distribution except that the probability is set to zero outside the range [-1000,1000]. The easiest way to do this is to pick a number according to a normal distribution, and if it's outside the desired range, just pick again.

```
SIGMA=10.0 # you can pick this value to be pretty much anything
def generate_number(average):
    x = random.normal_variate(average, SIGMA)
    while x > 1000 or x < -1000:
        x = random.normalvariate(average, SIGMA)
    return x
```

Here `SIGMA` is the standard deviation of the normal distribution, which governs how spread out the values will be. If `SIGMA` is small and `average` is not close to 1000 or -1000, or to be precise: if `(1000-average)/SIGMA` and `(1000+average)/SIGMA` are both larger than 2 or 3, then this method will be fairly efficient because it will usually hit a number within the desired range [-1000,1000] the first time. But if one of those ratios is small, like around 1 or less, then the algorithm will sometimes have to loop once or twice. That probably won't be a big deal. (If you wanted to avoid it there are advanced techniques you could use, but I don't think it'd be worth the complexity.)

Another option, which is kind of what your example code in the question does, is to drop the requirement of using a normal distribution entirely, and use some other probability distribution which is naturally restricted to a certain range. Your example code, equivalent to

```
random.triangular(-1000,1000,mode)
```

uses a distribution in which the probability increases linearly from -1000 to the `mode` and then decreases linearly from `mode` to 1000. The catch with this, though, is that `mode` is the value which has the largest probability of being chosen. It's not the same as the average of the numbers chosen. The actual average is `(min+max+mode)/3.`, or in your case, since `min+max = 1000-1000 = 0`, just `mode/3`, so if you wanted to generate numbers with a specified average, you would have to use

```
def generate_number(average):
    mode = 3*average
    if mode  < -1000 or mode > 1000:
        raise ValueError('Average cannot be satisfied: %f' % average)
    return random.normal_variate(-1000, 1000, mode)
```

Note that using this distribution means you can never produce numbers with an average less than `-1000./3.` or greater than `1000./3.`, unless you also adjust the min or max values accordingly.